# How to build OpenSSL using gcc or clang on OS X

Tags: macos, gcc, openssl, clang

I am building OpenSSL on OS X. I would like to understand more about modifying the build settings as described in the [Wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Modifying_Build_Settings).

I'm configuring the build as follows:

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc
make
```

How do I know which compiler this is going to use?

The Wiki has an example that indicates how to modify the build to use the clang compiler rather than gcc under the iOS 7.0 SDK.

I would like to modify my build to select one or the other of clang or gcc on OS X. The equivalent line in Configure is:

```
"darwin64-x86_64-cc","cc:-arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall::-D_REENTRANT:MACOSX:-Wl,-search_paths_first%:SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG RC4_CHUNK DES_INT DES_UNROLL:".eval{my $asm=$x86_64_asm;$asm=~s/rc4\-[^:]+//;$asm}.":macosx:dlfcn:darwin-shared:-fPIC -fno-common:-arch x86_64 -dynamiclib:.\$(SHLIB_MAJOR).\$(SHLIB_MINOR).dylib",
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I know which compiler this is going to use?

On modern OS X, you are usually getting one flavor of Clang or another:

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode-5_1.app/Contents/Developer/usr 
--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0
```

And even:

```
$ c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0
```

Apple Clang 5.1 is LLVM Clang 3.4. The preprocessor macros `__clang__`, `__clang_major__` and `__clang_minor__` are different values among Apple and LLVM. Its a real pain as you are working around Clang bugs. You may also need to detect Clang's integrated assembler, which brings in its own set of crushing bugs.

---

> I would like to modify my build to select one or the other of clang or gcc on OS X...

You can swap-in a compiler of your choosing, but you need to use `config` rather than `Configure`. Below is MacPort's GCC 6.0 compiler. Brew is probably similar (but I don't use it):

```
$ /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-6 --version
gcc-mp-6 (MacPorts gcc6 6.1.0_0) 6.1.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ CC=/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-6 KERNEL_BITS=64 ./config 
Operating system: i686-apple-darwinDarwin Kernel Version 12.6.0: Wed Mar 18 16:23:48 PDT 2015;
root:xnu-2050.48.19~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Configuring for darwin64-x86_64-cc
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
    no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
    no-jpake        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_JPAKE (skip dir)
    no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
    no-libunbound   [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_LIBUNBOUND (skip dir)
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP (skip dir)
    no-shared       [default] 
    no-ssl-trace    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE (skip dir)
    no-ssl2         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL2 (skip dir)
    no-store        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_STORE (skip dir)
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST (skip dir)
    no-weak-ssl-ciphers [default]  OPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS (skip dir)
    no-zlib         [default] 
    no-zlib-dynamic [default] 
IsMK1MF=0
CC            =/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-6
...
```

---

> What do I need to change?

Change the way you configure. Use `config` rather than `Configure`. Also use a *real* GCC compiler, and don't use a fake one created by a symbolic link.

There's also a bug report somewhere about Configure's inability to configure when doing something like `CC=/opt/local/bin/gcc ./Configure ...` You get a triplet like `linux-x86_64-/opt/local/bin/gcc`, which gets rejected later in the process.